# Cannot add cell to table view

Tags: swift, uikit

I'm new to this, I've just made an indexed table view "groups search" with all groups in my app and got a problem: when I'm trying to add some group to the "my groups" view, there are should appear a selected group, but actually I got the first one from all groups array instead. Also I can't add several items started with a similar letter in the "my groups". It might be stupid, but I have no idea how to fix that. Thank you!

```
import UIKit

final class AllGroupsViewController: UITableViewController {

 var groups = [
     "cats",
     "birds",
     "dogs",
     "books",
     "music",
     "movies",
     "art",
     "science",
     "tech",
     "beauty",
 ]
 var groupSectionTitles = [String]()
 var groupsDictionary = [String: [String]]()

 // MARK: - Lifecycle
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     tableView.register(UINib(
         nibName: "GroupCell",
         bundle: nil),
                        forCellReuseIdentifier: "groupCell")
     
     for group in groups {
         let groupKey = String(group.prefix(1))
         if var groupValues = groupsDictionary[groupKey] {
             groupValues.append(group)
             groupsDictionary[groupKey] = groupValues
         } else {
             groupsDictionary[groupKey] = [group]
         }
     }
     
     
     groupSectionTitles = [String](groupsDictionary.keys)
     groupSectionTitles = groupSectionTitles.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })
     
 }
 
 // MARK: - Table view data source
 override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
     return groupSectionTitles.count
 }
 
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     
     let groupKey = groupSectionTitles[section]
     if let groupValues = groupsDictionary[groupKey] {
         return groupValues.count
     }
     
     return 0
 }
 
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
     return groupSectionTitles[section]
 }
 
 override func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
     return groupSectionTitles
 }
 
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     guard
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "groupCell", for: indexPath) as? GroupCell
     else { return UITableViewCell() }
     
     var currentGroup = groups[indexPath.row]
     
     let groupKey = groupSectionTitles[indexPath.section]
     if let groupValues = groupsDictionary[groupKey] {
         currentGroup = groupValues[indexPath.row]
     }
     
     cell.configure(
         photo: UIImage(systemName: "person.3.fill") ?? UIImage(),
         name: currentGroup)

     return cell
 }

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     defer { tableView.deselectRow(
         at: indexPath,
         animated: true) }
     performSegue(
         withIdentifier: "addGroup",
         sender: nil)
 }

}
```

```
import UIKit

final class MyGroupsViewController: UITableViewController {
    var groups = [String]() {
        didSet {
            //
        }
    }
    
    
@IBAction func addGroup(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    guard
        segue.identifier == "addGroup",
        let allGroupsController = segue.source as? AllGroupsViewController,
        let groupIndexPath = allGroupsController.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow,
        !self.groups.contains(allGroupsController.groups[groupIndexPath.section])
    else { return }
    self.groups.append(allGroupsController.groups[groupIndexPath.section])
    tableView.reloadData()
}
    
    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UINib(
            nibName: "GroupCell",
            bundle: nil),
                           forCellReuseIdentifier: "groupCell")
    }
    
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        groups.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "groupCell", for: indexPath) as? GroupCell
        else { return UITableViewCell() }
        
        let currentGroup = groups[indexPath.row]

        cell.configure(
            photo: UIImage(systemName: "person.3.fill") ?? UIImage(),
            name: currentGroup)

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(
        _ tableView: UITableView,
        commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle,
        forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            groups.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(
                at: [indexPath],
                with: .fade)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not sure I get your question completely so let me try to explain what I understand. There is no issue with your UITableView set up - everything looks right - correct ? The only issue is when you transition to MyGroupsViewController, the wrong index is selected in this line of code `let groupIndexPath` ? Or is it something else ?

Comment: @ShawnFrank yes, you got it correctly. I've tried to set breakpoints in this line and there are wrong index has selected

Comment: I am trying to reproduce this at my end. I have some questions. Can you add some explanationing to your question to explain a little bit your UI flow. From `AllGroupsViewController` you tap on a cell and it takes you to `MyGroupsViewController`. What should show in the table view in this `MyGroupsViewController` and what is the purpose of this view ? Finally, I cannot see your storyboard set up so when is `@IBAction func addGroup(segue: UIStoryboardSegue)` called ? If you can add some of this info to your question, I think I can share some ideas to fix your issue.

Comment: @ShawnFrank so when I tap on a cell in `AllGroupsViewController` it takes me to `MyGroupsViewController` and the cell that I touched in `AllGroupsViewController` gotta will appear on the `MyGroupsViewController`. This project is a kind of a social network client, it's a study project. I can give you [link](https://github.com/tpolinas/UI_l1) to my repo with it, I'll be glad if you can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First here is what I understand the goal is:

1. There is a UITableViewController called `MyGroupsViewController` which should show all the groups the user has selected
2. On tapping on + from the `MyGroupsViewController`, the user is taken to another UITableViewController called `AllGroupsViewController` which shows all the groups the user can join
3. On selecting a UITableViewCell from `AllGroupsViewController`, you will `unwind` back to `MyGroupsViewController` showing the groups added for the user

I will say you were quite close and I have just added some minor things which I hope will bring you close to your goal.

One way to pass data between UIViewControllers when using segue transitions is to override a function called [prepare for segue (Read more about it in the Apple docs)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepareforsegue)

**1**

First change I will make is to add the `override prepareForSegue` to the end of the `MyGroupsViewController` class so that I can pass the groups array to the `AllGroupsViewController`

You can put it anywhere, I added it below your tableview editing function

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                            commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle,
                            forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            groups.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
    }
    
    // This was added by me
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Check the correct segue identifier and retrieve the destination
        if segue.identifier == "addGroup",
           let allGroupsViewController = segue.destination as? AllGroupsViewController
        {
            // Set the groups variable with data we stored in the
            // user groups array
            allGroupsViewController.userGroups = groups
        }
    }
```

**2**

In `AllGroupsViewController`, I added an array user groups to store all the groups the user taps on and the existing user's groups will be sent to it by `MyGroupsViewController` in step 1

```
class AllGroupsViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var groups = [
        "cats",
        "birds",
        "dogs",
        "books",
        "music",
        "movies",
        "art",
        "science",
        "tech",
        "beauty",
    ]
    
    // I added this. This will save groups the user wants
    var userGroups: [String] = []
```

**3.**

Then I made some small changes to your tableView `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function to store what the user has tapped

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                            didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        defer {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        }
        
        // Added by me: Retrieve the group tapped by the user
        let groupKey = groupSectionTitles[indexPath.section]
        var currentGroup = ""
        if let groupValues = groupsDictionary[groupKey] {
            currentGroup = groupValues[indexPath.row]
        }
        
        // Added by me: Check that this group was not added for the user
        // before to avoid duplicates
        if userGroups.firstIndex(of: currentGroup) == nil {
            userGroups.append(currentGroup)
        }
        
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "addGroup", sender: nil)
    }
```

**4**

Finally, back in `MyGroupsViewController`, I updated your `addGroup` unwind function slightly as follows:

```
    @IBAction func addGroup(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        guard segue.identifier == "addGroup",
              let allGroupsViewController = segue.source as? AllGroupsViewController
        else { return }
        
        // Added by me. Removed old code and added by me. Just update
        // the groups array with what was selected in AllGroupsViewController
        groups = allGroupsViewController.userGroups
        
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

You will get this end result with groups added to the user, without duplicates and also you are able to add groups with the same starting letter.

[image: Passing data between UITableViewControllers using segues here]

You can [watch the experience here on Youtube](https://youtu.be/nNBgQ4G9wDo)

If I missed something or did not answer something from your question, please add some more info / questions in the comments.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your help, but I think I explained UI flow a bit wrong. There are tab bar controller contains 2 TableVC, one of that is `MyGroupsViewController`. There are is segue from `MyGroupsViewController` to the `AllGroupsViewController`. In `AllGroupsViewController` user can choose one of the groups, tap on it and this selected item gotta appear on the `MyGroupsViewController` screen. 
So I've add your changes in my app and it works, but a quite strange. There are non-selected groups appears on the screen. You can watch this [here](https://youtu.be/eyWpRfvL0-s).

Comment: @t_polinas - can you commit recent code to your repo, I will see what changes you made there and update my answer. But now I think I understood your flow. `MyGroupsViewController` -> `AllGroupsViewController`. I select from `AllGroupsViewController` tableView, it should be added to table in `MyGroupsViewController` - right ? If yes, I think we are close.

Comment: Done. Yeah, that's right.

Comment: @t_polinas - I have updated answer, images and video links and I believe this is close to the goal you want to achieve.

Comment: Nailed it! Thank you so very very much for your help and explanations! I'm so appreciate it!